# Android Listview display multiple items per screen

Tags: android, json, listview

I've created a simple app that sends a search term to a php script, reads the json response generated by that php script based on the search term, processes the json response and loads the json nodes values in a listview. All goes well, the search is completed, the json gets processed, the values are loaded in the listview.

I have just one problem with the listview: each item is on a different screen.

This is my xml with the listview, called listview1.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_mresults"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the xml for each item, called listview1row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ref_pnr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ref_partnumber"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ref_pname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ref_part"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ref_supp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ref_supplier"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ref_avail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ref_available"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong? I've played with the layout width and height and with the layout of the listview, and nothing. Is there a specific combination of width and height i must use?
I've looked into some listview tutorials on some websites, copied the layout details from there and still nothing. I've looked at the json response and it does not contain any breaklines or carriage returns.

Edit: Below is the part where i set the adapter for the ListView.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Reference2.this, productsList,
                    R.layout.activity_reference3, new String[] { TAG_PNR,
                            TAG_PNAME, TAG_PSUPP, TAG_PAVAIL},
                    new int[] { R.id.ref_pnr, R.id.ref_pname, R.id.ref_supp, R.id.ref_avail });
            // updating listview
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, because you are using ListView, you should look at LayoutInflater to load the list values.

Here is an example on how to achieve it using LayoutInflater: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using linearLayout in your list item use layout_weight attribute on items based on your need.

Comment: I've tried that, it did not work either. I am looking at the LayoutInflater right now, as "openrijal" suggested. I am also thinking of putting the Textview and Listview from listview1.xml, each in his LinearLayout. I'll get back with a solution once i'll figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your adapters getView() method?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code where i set the adapter for the Listview.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found what the problem was. 
I was using android:background="@drawable/background". Once removed, everything worked as it should.
I came across this while i was rebuilding the listview1row.xml by hand instead of using the visual editor.

Thank you all for the answers and help!